# Vue Router router-view error

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm getting the following error when trying to implement vue-router.

`Unknown custom element: <router-view> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`

Where do I need to provide the name option?

A lot of the tutorials I'm looking at seem to be an older version of vue-router. I follow the set-up process but can't get it to work.

Might there be something special I have to do when using the webpack cli template?

I'm also using the vue-router cdn.

Here's my main.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import ResourceInfo from '../src/components/ResourceInfo'
var db = firebase.database();
var auth = firebase.auth();

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: App },
  { path: '/info', component: ResourceInfo }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

/* eslint-disable no-new */
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { App },
  created: function() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            // Get info for currently signed in user. 
            console.log(user);
            vm.currentUser = user;
             console.log(vm.currentUser);
        } else {
            // No user is signed in.
        }
    })
    // Import firebase data 
    var quizzesRef = db.ref('quizzes');
    quizzesRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
      vm.quizzes = snapshot.val();
      console.log(vm.quizzes);
    })

    var resourcesRef = db.ref('resources');
    resourcesRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
      vm.resources.push(snapshot.val());
      console.log(vm.resources);
    })

    var usersRef = db.ref('users');
    usersRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
      vm.users = snapshot.val();
      console.log(vm.users);
    })
  },
  firebase: {
    quizzes: {
        source: db.ref('quizzes'),
        asObject: true
    },
    users: {
        source: db.ref('users'),
        asObject: true
    }, 
    resources: db.ref('resources')
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
        users: {},
        currentUser: {},
        quizzes: {},
        resources: []
    }
  },
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

And my App.vue

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <navbar></navbar>
    <resource-info :current-user="currentUser"></resource-info>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import ResourceInfo from './components/ResourceInfo'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  props: ['current-user'],
  components: {
    Navbar,
    ResourceInfo
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Comment: Before you start typing your question, you may write `<!-- language-all: lang-js -->` which formats the code inside. It looks nice and improves readability. I have provided my answer below, which has syntax highlighted code. For more info, check out http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that. I'll use it next time!

Comment: I edited your question, with that syntax definition line at the top. No other changes anywhere, and now your code is formatted inside. It is a useful trick I also learnt recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **main.js** file, you need to import VueRouter as follows:

```js
import Vue from "vue"               // you are doing this already
import VueRouter from "vue-router"  // this needs to be done
```

And below that, you need to initialize the router module as follows:

```js
// Initialize router module
Vue.use(VueRouter)
```

Other than the above, I cannot find anything else missing in your code, it seems fine to me.

Please refer to the installation page in docs, under **NPM** section:
http://router.vuejs.org/en/installation.html

Comment: I'm importing Vue-router in a script tag in my html.

Comment: What about `Vue.use(VueRouter)`? That still needs to be done inside the main.js file. To do the above, you need to import again in main.js file, so that the dependency is resolved.

Comment: The installation page says *"You don't need to do this when using global script tags."* - which is for Vue **standalone** build. I believe you are using **runtime-only** build using webpack template or equivalent, right?

Comment: Adding Vue.use(VueRouter) seems to have solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First install vue router by using "npm install vue-route" and follow the bellow in main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import App from './App'
import ResourceInfo from '../src/components/ResourceInfo'
var db = firebase.database();
var auth = firebase.auth();

Vue.use(Router)
var router = new Router({
  hashbang: false,
  history: true,
  linkActiveClass: 'active',
  mode: 'html5'
})

router.map({
   '/': {
    name: 'app',
    component: App
  },
  '/info': {
    name: 'resourceInfo',
    component: ResourceInfo
  }
})
// If no route is matched redirect home
router.redirect({
  '*': '/'
});

// Start up our app
router.start(App, '#app')
```

This might be solve your problem

Comment: Just wanted to note that this looks right, but is relevant for vue-router 0.x only. There's a different API in v2.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to import **vue-router** and initialize VueRouter in main.js

```
import VueRouter from "vue-router"

Vue.use(VueRouter)
```